# How to make the newly created files inherit the directory's permissions...?

Tags: permissions, files, directory, chmod

I need to give permission to a directory in such a way that, the newly created files should inherit the same permissions as the directory.

- You may find a duplicate for this question, but it doesn't seems to be answered properly. So please update.

Comment: Says this is duplicate, but the answer here is better :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could assign a group ownership to a `parent` folder and then make inside files inherit properties.

Assigning group ownership could be set by

```
sudo chmod -R 660 /path/to/parent
sudo chown -R myself:somegroup /path/to/parent
```

The group ownership can be inherited by new files and folders created in your folder `/path/to/parent` by setting the `setgid` bit using `chmod g+s` like this:

```
chmod g+s /path/to/parent
```

Now, all new files and folder created under `/path/to/parent` will have the same group assigned as is set on `/path/to/parent`.

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/264383/how-to-set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions)

Comment: The person who posted that didn't clearly understand what they were doing. `myself:somegroup` is something you use with `chown`, and `660` with `chmod`. You can't mix one with the other.

Comment: @muru : Correct...! The following command did work... <sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/directory>  but newly created files are not inheritting the permissions. Whenever running the commands, they are getting altered....

Comment: This did not work for me. But this did work: `sudo find <path> -type d -exec chmod g+s '{}' \;`

Comment: Is there a way to do `chmod g+s /home/user` for the user? I tried `chmod u+s /home/user`, but only the group was the same as the parent dir, not the userid. ..or does setting just the gid is enough to placate applications that wont run on files in the user dir not owned by the user? related: https://superuser.com/questions/471844/why-is-setuid-ignored-on-directories "why-is-setuid-ignored-on-directories"